# How to increase default file upload limit in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform, file-upload

I am integrating file uploader in admin form. It's working fine. but it has default 2MB upload file size limit.

This is my uploader class

```
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    ....
}

public function uploadFile($scope)
{   
   try {
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $scope]);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

        if ($uploader->save($this->getBaseDir())) {
            return $uploader->getUploadedFileName();    
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception('The file was not uploaded.', $code);
    }
    return '';
}
```

How we increase file uploader limit?

Comment: Please check "upload_max_filesize" in phpInfo()

Comment: yes, it is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no Default setting in code:

Just update php.ini settings:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Hope this will work!!

Comment: Just to add, my php.ini was found at `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` which can be determined by adding a file containing this `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to the root of the server and browsing to it. As a final note, run `service apache2 reload` to get the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strange problem. We have our post_max_size set to 32M in our PHP ini. (php 7.2) But when I goto upload our logo in Content/Design/Config it says "Max limit 1kb"

Where is Magento getting that value?